# I want to use angular-js variable storing string as a source for image tag in HTML, how to achieve it?

Tags: angularjs

```
    sample.js
{...
$scope.temp=$scope.data[i].Src;
...
}
sample.html
{...
<img src={{temp}}>
...
}
```

> But when I am running it on chrome, its throwing error "http://localhost:9090/%7B%7Btemp%7D%7D", though fetching the image. Can anybody help me remove that error?

Comment: ng-src worked, thanks

Comment: You should look to close your question as a duplicate, then.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution (thanks to **Makoto**) , replacing "src" by "ng-src" worked.